# What is the difference between `assert_frame_equal` and `equals`

Tags: python, pandas, testing

I'm curious to find the difference between `assert_frame_equal` and `equal`.
Both are for checking the equality of two data. It applies for `assert_series_equal` and `assert_index_equal`. So what is the difference between equals and testing functions?

So far I found was testing functions gives little more flexibility to compare the values, like `check_dtpye` options etc., and differs from returning values Is this the only difference between them?

or otherwise,  When Should I use testing functions other than equals method?

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[6,7,8,9,10]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[6,7,8,9,10]})
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1,df2)
print df1.equals(df2)

pd.testing.assert_series_equal(df1['a'],df2['a'])
print df1['a'].equals(df2['a'])

pd.testing.assert_index_equal(df1.index,df2.index)
print df1.index.equals(df2.index)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`assert_frame_equal`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html) throws an `AssertionError` when two DataFrames aren't equal.

```
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)            # no result - pass

pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, pd.DataFrame()) # throws error - fail
# AssertionError
```

[`DataFrame.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) simply returns a boolean True/False.

```
df1.equals(df2)
# True

df1.equals(pd.DataFrame())
# False
```

This is also the case for the other functions defined in `pd.testing`, which are used to develop [unit tests](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/wiki/Testing) for pandas code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To find the equality of two data frames I can use equals, But when should I go with testing functions? at what stage I should apply testing functions rather than equals? please clear me I didn't really understand the difference +1 :)

Comment: @MohamedThasinah To clarify (perhaps I wasn't clear), you use the assert functions, mainly when writing unit test cases for your own code, when you would rather throw an AssertionError (and have the test fail) instead of querying the value of a boolean result. It's pretty much a matter of convention.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comment. Is there any other testing built-in-functions available rather than equality checking in pandas?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah I'd recommend checking out [this link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/wiki/Testing), and consider opening another post if you're not satisfied.