# Comparing OrderDict of DataFrames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, compare

I am facing a comparing problem, this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal

df1 = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
     'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
    'three' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e'])}

df2 = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
     'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
    'three' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e'])}
od = OrderedDict() 
od['a'] = pd.DataFrame(df1)
od['b'] = pd.DataFrame(df1)
od['c'] = pd.DataFrame(df1)
od['d'] = pd.DataFrame(df1)

od2 = OrderedDict() 
od2['a'] = pd.DataFrame(df2)
od2['b'] = pd.DataFrame(df2)
od2['c'] = pd.DataFrame(df2)
od2['d'] = pd.DataFrame(df2)

test = assert_frame_equal(od, od2)
print(test)
```

I have 2 OrderedDict made of pandas DataFrames and I would like to analyze if the single elements inside the DataFrames are equal.

I found the function assert_frame_equal that works perfectly when it comes to compare 2 DataFrames, but gives this error with OrderedDict:

> AssertionError: DataFrame Expected type class
>   'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame', found class
>   'collections.OrderedDict' instead

Is there any solution or workaround to this? Take into account that I necessarily start from an OrderedDict and unfortunately I cannot change that.

Thanks so much in advance any help/hint on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for df1, df2 in zip(od.values(), od2.values()):
    test = assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)
    print(test)
```

Returns:

```
None
None
None
None
```

Also, you are calling your initial `OrderedDict`s `df1`, which might lead to some confusion later on. By convention, `df` is short for `DataFrame`.

You can also use `equal`, per [What is the difference between `assert_frame_equal` and `equals`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51017249/what-is-the-difference-between-assert-frame-equal-and-equals)

```
for df1, df2 in zip(od.values(), od2.values()):
    test = df1.equals(df2)
    print(test)
```

Returns:

```
True
True
True
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Look if this helps. Using [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
for ord1, ord2 in zip(od.values(), od2.values()):

    print(assert_frame_equal(ord1, ord2))

    # or you can also use 
    print(ord1.equals(ord2))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The values in `od` and `od2` are dataframes, so I don't think the constructor needs to be called. `k` and `v` are shorthand for `key` and `value`, so using `k` to refer to `od.values()` may be confusing for some.

Comment: @Evan I agree with you.